Не меняется поле updated_at в sqlalchemy моделях, при изменениях во вложенной модели
Есть две модели SQLAlchemy:
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)

    records = relationship("Record", back_populates="owner")

class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = "records"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="records")

При обновлении поля records у user'а — поле updated_at не меняется, можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы оно автоматически менялось как при изменении поля самой модельки?
Например,  я меняю record, которая связана с user'ом, но поле updated_at у user'а не меняется
